# how to modify only some object properties dinamically

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I have this object (that has a lot more properties than listed here, having different values):

```
var dbValuesObj = {
    //1. group of properties that I don't want to touch(I don't want to check the values for these)
    rebateNetSaleMinAmt1: 500,
    rebateNetSaleMaxAmt1: 400,
    rebateAmtWoProd1: 0,
    rebateAmtAllProd1: 200,
    rebateAmtOneProd1: 0,

    //2. group of properties that I want to change (I know exactly what is the list of the properties that I want to check and change their values, if they are equal to 0)
    rebateNetSaleMinAmt2: 100,
    rebateNetSaleMaxAmt2: 0,
    rebateAmtWoProd2: 300,
    rebateAmtAllProd2: 0,
    rebateAmtOneProd2: 700
}
```

I need to change the values for the object properties from point #2 that have value 0.
So in my case, I want to change rebateNetSaleMaxAmt2 and rebateAmtAllProd2 to a different value. But I don't want to check or change properties from #1

I have tried using

```
for(var property in dbValuesObj)
```

but I checks all the properties and I don't want to look/change/check the properties from #1

Comment: Do you have a list of properties that you want to change and what should be their final value?

Comment: `if (property ends with "2" and the value is zero) { ... }`

Comment: Hi. So I know exactly the list of properties that I want to check. So yeah, i have a list. I also know the value that I want to assign to them if their value is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how i resolved my issue
Thanks everyone for the answers

```
//Define the properties that we want to check for 0 value
    var arrayOfPropsToCheck = ["rebateNetSaleMinAmt1", "rebateNetSaleMaxAmt1", "rebateAmtWoProd1", "rebateAmtAllProd1", "rebateAmtOneProd1",
                               "rebateNetSaleMinAmt2", "rebateNetSaleMaxAmt2", "rebateAmtWoProd2", "rebateAmtAllProd2", "rebateAmtOneProd2",
                               "rebateNetSaleMinAmt3", "rebateNetSaleMaxAmt3", "rebateAmtWoProd3", "rebateAmtAllProd3", "rebateAmtOneProd3",
                               "rebateNetSaleMinAmt4", "rebateNetSaleMaxAmt4", "rebateAmtWoProd4", "rebateAmtAllProd4", "rebateAmtOneProd4",
                               "rebateNetSaleMinAmt5", "rebateNetSaleMaxAmt5", "rebateAmtWoProd5", "rebateAmtAllProd5", "rebateAmtOneProd5",
                               "rebateNetSaleMinAmt6", "rebateNetSaleMaxAmt6", "rebateAmtWoProd6", "rebateAmtAllProd6", "rebateAmtOneProd6",
                               "rebateNetSaleMinAmt7", "rebateNetSaleMaxAmt7", "rebateAmtWoProd7", "rebateAmtAllProd7", "rebateAmtOneProd7"];

    //Check the properties in the dbValuesObj object
    for (var property in dbValuesObj) {

      //Get the value for the property
      var value = dbValuesObj[property];

      //Define flag
      var isInArray = false;

      //Get the values from the arrayOfPropsToCheck
      for(var k = 0; k < arrayOfPropsToCheck.length; k++){

        //Compare if the name of the property is equal to the one found in the array and set flag to true
        if(arrayOfPropsToCheck[k] == property){
          isInArray = true;
        }
      }
      //If propery is in arrayOfPropsToCheck and has value 0 change it to empty string
      if(isInArray && value === "0"){
          dbValuesObj[property] = ""; 
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to change the values for the object properties from point #2
>   that have value 0. So in my case, I want to change
>   rebateNetSaleMaxAmt2 and rebateAmtAllProd2 to a different value.

You can filter them out first

```
var requiredKeys = Object.keys( dbValuesObj ).filter( k => k.slice(-1) == "2" && dbValuesObj[k] == 0 );
```

Now you can iterate this `requiredKeys` array

```
requiredKeys.forEach( function( key ){
   console.log( key, dbValuesObj[key]  )
})
```

For data you have provided, it will print

> "rebateNetSaleMaxAmt2" 0
>
> "rebateAmtAllProd2" 0

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the `property` ends with "2" and whether the property's `value` is 0.

To get the last value from the `property` string you can do the following:

`property[property.length-1];`

Then to get the `value` of the property you can do this:

`dbValuesObj[property];`

Now that you know how to get required components you can use an if statement in you for loop to check whether or not the property meets your requirements (ends with "2" and has a value of 0) and then change the value to whatever you want it to be. (in the code snippet I am setting it to 1)

Check the code snippet for a working example:

```js
var dbValuesObj = {
  rebateNetSaleMinAmt1: 500,
  rebateNetSaleMaxAmt1: 400,
  rebateAmtWoProd1: 0,
  rebateAmtAllProd1: 200,
  rebateAmtOneProd1: 0,
  
  rebateNetSaleMinAmt2: 100,
  rebateNetSaleMaxAmt2: 0,
  rebateAmtWoProd2: 300,
  rebateAmtAllProd2: 0,
  rebateAmtOneProd2: 700
}

for (var property in dbValuesObj) {
  var value = dbValuesObj[property];
  if (property[property.length - 1] === "2" && value === 0) {
    dbValuesObj[property] = 1; // Change the value to a new value (ie 1)
  }
}

console.log(dbValuesObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateGroup(obj, defaultValue, grpNum) {
  for(prop in obj ) {
   var index = parseInt(prop.match(/\d+$/)[0]);

   if(index === grpNum && obj[prop] === 0) {
    obj[prop] = defaultValue;
   } 
   if(index > grpNum) { // if properties are in number order. else remove this.
    return;
  }}

  return; 
}
```

`updateGroup(dbValuesObj, 100, 2);`

You can try this by giving groupNumber and defaultValue you what to set for `0` in that group.